# How to pass non-optimizing arguments into fitness function in GA package

Tags: r

I use GA package in R (an R package for optimisation using genetic algorithms) and need to optimize fitness function F(x1, x2, A_dataframe, b_const), where
  x1 - variable for optimization, min=0, max=1.
  x2 - variable for optimization, min=2, max=3.
  A_dataframe - a data frame which is not optimization variable, but known data frame needed for fitness function calculation.
  b_const - a constant variable which is not for optimization too, but known variable needed for fitness function calculation.
  So fitness function=F.

I try to use the next code.

```
TotalFunction <- function(A_dataframe, b_const) {

    F <- function(x1, x2, A_dataframe, b_const) {
        #code of fitness function
    }

    GA <- ga(type="real-valued", fitness=function(x) F(x[1], x[2], A_dataframe, b_const),
    A_dataframe, b_const, min=c(0, 2), max=(1, 3), popSize=50, maxiter=100)

    return(GA)
}
```

Could you help me create right ga-function. Is it possible to pass a known data frame into fitness function through ga-function? Thanks a lot.

Comment: To clarify: do you want `TotalFunction` to return the result of `ga`, or a function that calls `ga`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest moving your fitness function outside of `TotalFunction` to improve readability and avoid name collision / confusion.

```
F <- function( x1, x2, A_dataframe, b_const ) {
    #code of fitness function
}
```

Given the above definition of `F`, you can call the `ga` function with pre-specified values of `A_dataframe` and `b_const` as following:

```
## A <- ... define your data frame
## B <- ... define your constant
result <- ga(type="real-valued", fitness=function(x) F(x[1], x[2], A, b),
    min=c(0, 2), max=(1, 3), popSize=50, maxiter=100)
```

This will correctly utilize your fitness function `F` using pre-defined values of parameters `A_dataframe`, and `b_const`. To make this dynamically depend on `A` and `B`, we can wrap this into a function:

```
ga_Ab <- function( A, b )
{
  ga(type="real-valued", fitness=function(x) F(x[1], x[2], A, b),
    min=c(0, 2), max=(1, 3), popSize=50, maxiter=100)
}
```

Comment: Artem, thank you very much (spasibo). My mistake was  that I repeated names of pre-defined variables after definition of function. I should use result <- ga(type="real-valued", fitness=function(x) F(x[1], x[2], A_dataframe, b_const), min=c(0, 2), max=(1, 3), popSize=50, maxiter=100) instead of result <- ga(type="real-valued", fitness=function(x) F(x[1], x[2], A_dataframe, b_const),  A_dataframe, b_const, min=c(0, 2), max=(1, 3), popSize=50, maxiter=100)